# The block $617$ occurs infinitely many times in the decimal expansion of almost every $x ∈ [0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Prove that, for *almost everywhere* number $x ∈ [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains the
block **$617$** (for instance, $x = 0.3375617264 ···$), that block occurs infinitely
many times in the decimal expansion of $x$. Even more, the block $617$ occurs
infinitely many times in the decimal expansion of almost every $x ∈ [0,1]$.

The first part I did taking $E = [0, 617, 0, 618)$ which has positive measure and use that the Lebesgue measure is $f$-invariant where $f(x)=10x- \lfloor 10x \rfloor$ and apply the recurrence theorem
of Poincaré.

The second part the book gives a hint:

Note that every interval $J = [ j / 10^k, (j + 1) / 10^k)$ contains subinterval $J'$ such that
$\frac{m (J')}{m (J)} = \frac{1}{10^{3}}$ and $f^k (x) ∈ E$ for all $x ∈ J'$. 
Using **Theorem** $A.2.14$, conclude that
all $x ∈ [0, 1]$ has at least one iterate in $E$. Now the second statement in the exercise the is consequence of the first part.

**Theorem** $A.2.14.$ Let A be a measurable subset of $R^d$ with Lebesgue measure
$m(A)$ positive. Then $m$-almost every $a ∈ A$ is a density point of $A$.

I can not see that there is this interval $ J '$. Someone can explain.

Comment: There's something fishy about the first claim.  The number all of whose decimal digits are (say) 3, except for the initial block of 617,  viz $x=.61733333...$ looks like a counter example. Maybe you mis-stated what you meant to ask?

Comment: The first claim as stated is plainly wrong.  I wonder if what is meant is that it's true of *almost* every $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: The correct is for almost everywhere number $x∈[0,1]$

Comment: Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: I can not see relation in using Borel cantelli and explain the existence of the interval $J'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ J' = \left[\frac{10^3j+617}{10^{k+3}}, \frac{10^3j+618}{10^{k+3}} \right) $$